# Recurring crash from Google app with error message "EXCLUSIVE background task UPDATE_HOTWORD_MODELS crashed"

Tags: google, system-error

My mom's Xiaomi phone started displaying the error message:

> The Google application has suffered an error again. Please send a report to Xiaomi.

The code under the "see more" button is extensive, but the gist of it is that the "EXCLUSIVE background task UPDATE_HOTWORD_MODELS crashed".

The error message pops up every 2 seconds. What should I do to help my mom return her phone to a usable condition? Restarts do not help; I purged the settings of Google apps, that did not help either.

Comment: Did this start happening after an update? Go into your Settings and then Apps, look for the Google app, go into it on the Play store and uninstall updates. That will return it to an earlier state.
Restart phone then see if message stops and you're able to use 'Hey Google' again.
If it works, then update the Google app again so its current and see if it works now.

Comment: @NetServOps - thank you, I'll try it!

Answer (score 2):

**This seemed to be caused by the latest update (12.22.8.23, 12.23.16.23.arm64, 12.24.7.29.arm64 beta) to the Google App.**

As covered by many sources, the issue was caused by an update to the Google app and affected other features that use Google app:

- [XDA Forums - It’s not just you: Google App is crashing for many Android users](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-app-crashing-android/)
- [Android Authority - Is your Google app crashing? You're not alone. (Updated: Fix incoming)](https://www.androidauthority.com/google-app-crashing-1237738/)
- [Android Police - Google app crashing constantly? Here's how you could fix it](https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/06/22/google-app-crashing-constantly-heres-how-you-could-fix-it/)
- [NDTV - Gadgets360 - Google App on Android Phones Across Brands Crashing After Recent Update, Users Report](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/google-app-android-phone-crash-update-bug-issue-user-report-reddit-twitter-version-12-23-16-23-arm64-2469733)
- [9to5Google - Google app repeatedly crashing after latest update on Android; here’s how to officially fix [U]](https://9to5google.com/2021/06/22/google-app-crashing/)

**Known problematic versions**:

- 12.22.8.23
- 12.23.16.23.arm64
- 12.24.7.29.arm64 (beta)

**Affected apps and features**:

- Google app
- Google Podcasts
- Google Lens
- Google Assistant

#### Possible fixes

- **Uninstall the problematic update**:

  Settings > Apps & notifications > See all > [scroll to] Google > overflow menu (in the top-right corner) > Uninstall updates
- [**Clear Google's data**](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/114512880/regarding-the-google-app-crashing)

  Settings > Apps & notifications > See all apps > [scroll to] Google > Storage & cache > Clear storage / Manage space > Clear all data

  Note: This will clear some settings for the Google app.  Please review the settings if you have changed from default.
- [**Join Beta program**](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/join)